# jquery-ias jQuery doesn't work for loaded items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ias

Here is the problem, I understood that for new items we should add the rendered event, here is my code but jQuery still doesn't work for new items, what I'm doing wrong ?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dwn').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().css({
    'opacity': '0.3'
  })
}, function() {
  $('.view').css({
    'opacity': '1'
  })
});
});
```

With rendered :

```
 ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    var $items = $(items);
    $items.each(function() {
    $('.dwn').hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().siblings().css({
        'opacity': '0.3'
      })
    }, function() {
      $('.view').css({
        'opacity': '1'
      })
    });
    });
    });
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event listener on element that contains items you want to do something on hover it. The biggest and universal handler can be $('html'). You must explode your .hover() to two events listeners. Modified code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').on('mouseover', '.dwn', function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().css({
      'opacity': '0.3'
    });
  });
  $('html').on('mouseout', '.dwn', function() {
    $('.view').css({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
  });
});
```